# Common datas write to another table ? Join or parse code?

Tags: sql, oracle, parsing, join

Hello Guys I need a query that "write all datas that match (table1.column1) =table2.column2)  to  table3" in the other word;
I have two table and one columns are common both of them, and I want to select all rows which datas are same in these columns and write them to another table.

Here is my tables seem;
(these columns datatypes are table1: `varchar2(500char)` table2: `varchar2(50byte)`

Table1

```
ecno
213-408-0
204-114-3
223-874-7
213-447-3

...
```

Table2

```
ecno
244-472-8
213-408-0
223-134-7
213-447-4
...
```

When I execute this query(I use oracle 11g):

```
select k.ecno from kimyasal k JOIN A_REFLIST a ON K.EC_NO=A.ECNO
```

No rows return. But I know there are hundreds common datas in these columns.
My question is:

- Is the reason that not work related with;”columns data type sizes are different ?” or something like that ?
- How can I do it well ? What type of query should I try ? or I heard something about need to parse datas, is it  necessary ?
- And When the common rows return I need to write all rows which return to
  another table(table3). Is this possible with query ?

Thank you who try to help.

Comment: Strange. Maybe additional blanks in one of the field? Try TRIM() and see if this solves your problem.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Hello, I try it returns only "-" rows in both columns have same value which means "no ecno". But I want to get only same numbers columns exist in both of them.

Comment: The idea was that maybe one table contains '213-408-0' and the other contains '213-408-0   ', which you might consider equal whereas the dbms treats them as different entries. Seams not to be the case. Does WHERE ecno = '213-408-0' succeed on both tables?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Wow, its really logical and right. table2 succeed return a value but table1 doesnt return. I think table1's columns datatype isnt match with others but I dont understand how can it be ?
bot of them varchar2..

Comment: I got it now.. all the rows of table1 columns has a blank character at the end of line so = condition return false. You were right from the beginning :) Thank you. And can I ask you a question How can I follow you can I get a contact info

Comment: now the question is how can I delte all the blank character of table1 columns :))

Comment: To have your select match: JOIN A_REFLIST a ON TRIM(K.EC_NO)=TRIM(A.ECNO) . To delete blank records: UPDATE table1 set ecno = TRIM(ecno) WHERE ecno != TRIM(ecno);

Comment: here is my query;
INSERT INTO table3(column1,column2,column3)
SELECT k.column1,A.column2 , A.column3
FROM SEVESO.KIMYASAL k JOIN SEVESO.A_REFLIST a on trim(K.EC_NO)=trim(A.ECNO)



But it insert 56000 rows :SS 
table1 has 4000 rows , table2 has 3500 rows, 
so inner join querys should return less than 3500 ? doesnt it ?

Comment: This is because you have '-' in your column rather than NULL when there is no number present. There are many '-' entries from table k matching many '-' entries in table a, thus multiplying the resulting records. Exclude '-': ON trim(K.EC_NO) = trim(A.ECNO) AND trim(K.EC_NO) != '-' AND trim(A.ECNO) != '-' . (It would be better if the tables contained NULL instead of '-', then the problem wouldn't even exist.)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I done it, 3077 rows returned now. Thank you so much.

Comment: Hi, I've added an answer you can accept and have me earning some points :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues in your data:

1. some values have trailing space
2. a minus sign represents "no data"

You solve this by

```
ON trim(K.EC_NO) = trim(A.ECNO) AND trim(K.EC_NO) != '-' AND trim(A.ECNO) != '-'
```

Having said this, it would of course be better to avoid this problematic data in the first place:

1. Remove spaces:

   UPDATE tablex set ecno = TRIM(ecno) WHERE ecno != TRIM(ecno);
2. Delete the minus signs:

   UPDATE tablex set ecno = NULL WHERE TRIM(ecno) = '-';
3. Write before-insert/update triggers to clean up data on insert or update.

Answer (score 0):

Your Inner Join should work, another solution would be with an **Exists** clause but I don't think it would be useful in your case. You can also CAST your value to Varchar2(500) to be sure your comparing the same type.

```
 INSERT INTO Table3(name_of_your_column)
    SELECT k.EC_NO
    FROM kimyasal k
    WHERE EXISTS 
          (SELECT 1 FROM A_REFLIST a WHERE CAST(a.ECNO as VARCHAR2(500)) = k.EC_NO)
```

Comment: Hello FloChanz, Thank you for answer but not work :(